# Python Try/Except firing TypeError despite Except clause

Tags: python, django, try-catch

I'm following along with the Python docs for try/except with the following effort:

```
def profile_check(self):
    try:
        profile = self.profile_type
        return profile
    except TypeError:
        ...
```

`self.profile_type` is a field in a Django model which **doesn't exist in this case** (therefore it returns as None). However, something seems to be missing, because it never moves on to the actions for `except`, rather it immediately throws the TypeError exception:

```
>>> a.profile_check()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

This is my first effort with try-catch, so I know it's something basic.

Comment: Are you sure the code you posted is the part throwing the error?

Comment: What is `a`? Looks like `a.profile_check` is `None`.

Comment: The exception can only be caught in the `try` block. If you never even enter it in the first place, well...

Comment: `a` is the database object that is filling in for `self` in this attempt. I know it is occurring in the try block, because it will print a statement before setting the profile variable, but not afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your problem is that profile_check is set to `None` for some reason. That's why it's giving you that error when you call it.

As for your try/catch problem, if a variable doesn't exist, then the Python interpreter will throw a `NameError` at you. Try substituting `TypeError` for that.

I can't help you with your profile_check-is-None situation though without anymore context though. Sorry!

Comment: `profile_check` is a formula that checks for the existence of a value in the database. In this case, it is supposed to be None. My hope was that this function would move in if the value didn't exist. Maybe it's best to change back to an if-then statement. As you can see, I'm getting a TypeError, not a NameError. Substituting NameError still gives me the same TypeError.

Comment: @AdamStarrh How can you expect to call a function if it is set to None? :P

Comment: @stanpipes I rather figured I'd get an error that I could use with `except`. In some cases, the function will return a value. I suppose I could change `None` to some sort of signal value and move on, if what I'm trying isn't going to work. I am more or less attempting to learn how to use a try-catch.

Comment: @AdamStarrh Ah, yes. Functions don't do any exceptions if they are null. That means they can't be called. You can do a check exactly like the one you did in the question, like this

`
try:
    a.profile_check()
except TypeError:
    print "It's set to null!"
`

Comment: @stanpipes I see. So what is the source of the TypeError that I am receiving in the shell in this case?

Comment: The error you are receiving is because you can't call a value that is set to None.